# Create one image from multiple images in C#

Tags: c#, .net, image, bitmap

I need to combine multiple images into one image. This I managed to do.
However, I need these images to have specific positions within the final image. To do this, I need to use `Bitmap` with `Graphics`, however, I am a little bit confused on how to do this.

For Example:

I have 4 images files (`img1.png`, `img2.png`, `img3.png`, `img4.png`), I need to create one single image with these four images in it at the specified pixel coordinates:

1. `img1.png` dimensions: top=20px, left=30px, width: 70px, height: 50px
2. `img2.png` dimensions: top=70px, left=80px, width: 50px, height: 30px
3. `img3.png` dimensions: top=120px, left=30px, width: 110px, height: 80px
4. `img4.png` dimensions: top=12px, left=200px, width: 70px, height: 90px

Answer (score 3):

First create an image using the total width & height. Need to calculate the width & height from the images which are going to stitch on a single image. Now use below code to stitch:

```
using (Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(cal_width, cal_height))
{
    using (Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(bmp))
    {
        g.DrawImage(img1,x1,y1,w1,h1);
        g.DrawImage(img2, x2, y2, w2, h2);
        g.DrawImage(img3, x3, y3, w3, h3);
        g.DrawImage(img4, x4, y4, w4, h4);
    }
}
```

`bmp` will the desired image. `x1`,`y1`...`x4`,`y4` are the positions of the top left point from where you start place the image. These positions need to calculate in respective to the final image. Also place the width & height of the images using `w1`,`h1`...`w4`,`h4`.

Comment: But, the DrawImage function uses the points like dimensions, however, I have pixels.